# JavaScript: Can a constructor function create a documentElement object?

Tags: javascript, dom, functional-programming, constructor

I want to make a constructor function that creates a documentElement object.

As an example, consider the new Audio() constructor - it creates a documentElement object, and if you pass it some variables it populates the new documentElement with attributes.  It doesn't insert it into the DOM, it simply creates the object.

So, the question is - what makes a documentElement different from a vanilla javascript object (of the {property: value} kind), and can you write constructors for them like you can for objects?

Edit:

What I'm toying with is re-creating the new Audio() constructor in browsers that don't have it, using a quicktime or flash HTMLObjectElement in place of the HTMLAudioElement.

It's ok with me that audio.constructor will refer to HTMLObjectElement, as the result of using new Audio() in browsers that support it, is that audio.constructor refers to HTMLAudioElement.

I'm not sure about the Audio.prototype.  When I query console.log(Audio.prototype) in browsers with Audio support, they return nothing at all - not even an empty line in console.log - so that's got me stumped. If I understand right, though, it doesn't affect what I'm aiming to do.

The aim is to be able to code using the Audio constructor, and have the browser handle it natively or set up a plugin instance if it needs to.

Comment: I've just seen a note here that helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/javascript-detect-if-function-called-as-constructor

Claudia says:
If a constructor function returns an object, that is used instead of <em>this</em>

Comment: The `Audio` constructor creates a `documentElement`? Do you have some references? Because I don't know of any `Audio` constructor.

Comment: It's new. It accompanies html5 and enables you to play sounds from javascript. Check out the bottom half of the blog post http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: I know about the audio stuff in HTML5, but I had no idea there's a JavaScript constructor for this. I thought you'd have to query the DOM for an `audio` tag in order to get access to the audio API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document) element is not a plain JavaScript object, is a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element) object, that implements the general *DOM Core* **[document interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document)**.

You can create documentElements by using  [document.implementation.createDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocument) (available from [DOM Core Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)):

```
function createDocument() {
 var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
                                                      'html',  null),
     body = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'body');  

  doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);  
  return doc;
}
```

**Edit:**

Do you mean something like this?

```
function ElementCreator(tagName, attributes){
    this.element = document.createElement(tagName);

    for (var i in attributes) {
      this.element[i] = attributes[i];
    }
  return this.element;
}

var anchor = new ElementCreator('a', { id: 'myLink', href:'http://google.com',
                                       innerHTML:'Link text' });
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
// <a id="myLink" href="http://google.com">Link text</a>
```

However I don't see too much advantage of using a constructor function for that.

The element is returned from the constructor function, the object `instance` is lost, `anchor.constructor` in the above example refers to `HTMLAnchorElement` instead of `ElementCreator`, and for that the access to the `ElementCreator.prototype` is also lost.

It would make more sense if the DOM Element instance is wrapped on a member, or just implement a simple function.

Comment: Sorry if I've not been clear.  You've misunderstood.  I want to write a constructor function (not just a function) that will create documentElements (not documents) in the way that document.createElement('tag') does.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. That's setting me on the right track.  I've responded to your concerns in an edit to the question, above...

Comment: I think your terminology is a bit confused. By a “documentElement” do you simply mean a DOM Node?

Comment: Yes. But surely it's not a DOM node until it's in the DOM?

Comment: @stephband: a DOM node is a DOM node, whether it's currently part of a document or not. It can't stop being a DOM node when it's removed from a document; and if it isn't a DOM node when it's created, then it can't be inserted into a document, for documents can only contain DOM nodes.

Comment: Ok, then please excuse me for confusing the issue. But that is a part of the answer I'm looking for - what makes a DOM Node object different from a plain vanilla javascript object?

Comment: A DOM Node is one of the many objects that are permitted to be a “host object”. Most of JavaScript's guarantees about what happens with prototyping and “native objects” don't hold for host objects.