# Is there a way for a JavaScript function to know whether it was called normally or in conjunction with "new"?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if a function is called as constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor)

I would like to have a function in JavaScript which behaves differently if it's called normally or if it's invoked in order to create a new instance. There could be many different uses, where the two functionalities can be related or not related. One use would be to exempt the coder from having to type `new`, when the function is always used to create new instances:

```
function MyClass(arg1, arg2) {
  if(/* not called with "new" */) return new MyClass(arg1, arg2);

  // instance initialization stuff here...

}
```

This way I wouldn't have to type `var x = new MyClass(arg1, arg2)`: it would be enough to type `var x = MyClass(arg1, arg2)` (but the former wouldn't be wrong either).

Just one example of a possible use.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry for missing the duplicate - I should have looked for the keyword "constructor"... Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to be absolutely sure how the function was called, but you can be pretty sure using `this instanceof MyClass`, like so:

```
if (this instanceof MyClass) {
    // Was called with `new`
} else {
    // Was called as regular function
}
```

There are edge cases though, e.g. I could create a new instance of MyClass and then do `MyClass.call(new MyClass)` -- this would create a false positive, as the outer `MyClass` was not called with `new`.

Comment: I took this as a basis, and added a twist: when initializing a new instance I set a flag on it. So when the function is called I check 1) that `this` is `instanceof` my class, and 2) that its flag is still not set. If both conditions hold - it's `new` (in which case I set the flag and do whatever else I do). If not, I know it's an ordinary function call (even if from another method of the class).

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can think of here is to test the value of `this`. You might try:

```
function MyClass(args) {
    var isInstance = this instanceof MyClass;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this instanceof MyClass)
```

is probably what you're looking for. It can be fooled with `.call` and `.apply`, but there shouldn't be any problem constructing the object if an instance is passed, anyway.