# Detecting if the new keyword was used inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, object

In a constructor object in JS if it's created without the new keyword the 'this' variable is a reference to the window instead of the object. Is this a particularly wise idea to try and detect that?

```
function MyObject ()
{
    if (this === window) {
        alert('[ERROR] Oopsy! You seem to have forgotten to use the "new" keyword.');
        return;
    }

    // Continue with the constructor...
}

// Call the constructor without the new keyword
obj = MyObject()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a function is called as constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor)

Comment: Your code doesn't detect things like `var obj = MyObject.call(foo)`

Comment: Sorry, why would you *want* to? Describe the preferred usage in your documentation, but it is ultimately up to the developer as to how they want to use/implement your object. That's the beauty of programming/scripting.

Comment: @zamnuts there are many cases where you want to be sure you were called with new.  For example, if MyObject has a name, and you go this.name = 'Fred', you just wiped out window.name if this wasn't called with a new.  Not want you wanted and will probably cause a bug.

Comment: @user949300 Whose fault is that? The implementor's. IMO, it is one thing to clean up after "stupid" users (end-user/consumer), it is another thing to compensate for incompetent developers. From the POV of an advanced dev: You're telling me I can't use the module you've developed in a manner that suites me? Fine, I'll refactor your lib or roll my own, and either case send you hate mail for wasting my time.

Comment: I want to protect/inform the users of my library that they're doing something wrong.The .call() method makes things a little trickier though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is fairly common to force a **new** object when the keyword is omitted-

```
function Group(O){
    if(!(this instanceof Group)) return new Group(O);
    if(!O || typeof O!= 'object') O= {};
    for(var p in O){
        if(O.hasOwnProperty(p)) this[p]= O[p];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `new.target` property was designed specifically for this purpose:

```js
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) { throw 'Foo() must be called with new'; }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target

Answer (score 0):

I found this in SO, the last answer uses your approach;

> Two ways, essentially the same under the hood. You can test what the
>   scope of this is or you can test what this.constructor is.

but the accepted one says no reliable way to do that;

[How to detect if a function is called as constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor)

EDIT.

In the book Javascript Enlightment mentions that not necesarily will be window but the parent object;

> On the other hand, if you create a constructor function and call it
>   without the use of the new keyword the this value will refer to the
>   “parent” object that contains the function.