# Distinguish between a constructor and a normal function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'd like to call a function without knowing how it should be called/instantiated. For my understanding there are two ways we can either use `new Foo()` or `Foo()`.

As I need a wrapper to call this function, let's say it's basically a proxy. I have a reference to a function but don't know in which way I should call it, wether it is meant to be a constructor or a plain javascript function.

As it seems that there is no way to distuingish between both ways I came up with the following.

```
var delegate;
var Foo = function() { };
    Foo.prototype.foo = function() { alert("foo") };

var bar = function(value) { alert(value); } 

function construct(constructor, args) {
    function F() {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new F();
}

var proxy = function() { return construct(delegate, arguments) };

delegate = bar;
proxy("bar");

delegate = Foo;
new proxy().foo();
```

This gives me the expected result and seems to work. Do you see anything bad with this solution? Is it bad to call a regular function with `new`? What are the downside of this technique?

The code is based on the following question ["Use of apply with the new operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to distinguish between a constructor and a normal function?

No. Every normal (user-defined) javascript function can act as both. From inside the function, you might do some reasoning depending on how the `this` value looks like, but this is not reliable.

See also [How to detect if a function is called as constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367768/1048572)

> I have a reference to a function but don't know in which way I should call it, wether it is meant to be a constructor or a plain javascript function.

However, you don't need to know that - `proxy` itself is called as either as a constructor or plain function by someone who knows it.

> Do you see anything bad with my solution?

That closure over `delegate` which is later changed is ugly when left in the open. In your case you don't really seem to need it, a plain `proxy = bar;` and `proxy = Foo;` would be sufficient there. Also, your `construct` function looks unnecessary.

> Is it bad to call a regular function with new? What are the downside of this technique?

If the function does not use `this`, then no problems will arise, but there's overhead in constructing the instance object.

For a proxy function that is passed somewhere else (so that we cannot easily change the reference), I'd use an explicit setter for `delegate`:

```
function makeProxy(delegate) {
    function proxy() {
        return delegate.apply(this, constructor);
    }
    proxy.prototype = delegate.prototype;
    return {
        proxy: proxy,
        setTarget: function(d) {
            delegate = d;
            proxy.prototype = d.prototype;
        }
    };
}

var p = makeProxy(bar);
p.proxy("bar");

p.setTarget(Foo);
new (p.proxy)().foo();
```