# New instance of function with object property

Tags: javascript

### Function are first class objects in JavaScript - but how to use that in combination with `new`?

I get how to make an object that acts both like a function and like an object

```
fetch.proxy = '127.0.0.1'
fetch(url)
```

But I am trying to figure out how I can combine this with creating a `new` intance so I can do something along the lines of:

```
a = new Fetch(host, username) 

a(path1) // fetches username@host/path1

a(path2) // fetches username@host/path2
```

*(not so useful example with only 1 instance)*

The following approach does not work as applying `new` returns an object (so get `TypeError: object is not a function`).

```
var Fetch = function(a, b){

    if ( (this instanceof arguments.callee) ){
        //called as constructor
        this.host = a
        this.username = b;
        this.host = 'localhost'

    } else {

   //called as function
   console.log("Fetching "+this.username+'@'+this.host+a);
    }
};

a = new Fetch('host', 'username') 

a('/path1') // TypeError: object is not a function

a('/path2') // TypeError: object is not a function
```

I have been playing with `Fetch.prototype.constructor` based on http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/ and [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property) but must admit I have started to question if its possible at all.

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: Would you accept an `Factory` way instead of `New`?

Comment: i think you have some very good replies info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor

Comment: you may need to pass both arguments **(a,b)**  else you can pass it by making object's key value so the no. of argument's will not make difference to you r code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use that in combination with `new`?

It doesn't make sense to do that. All that `new Foo` does is create a new object that inherits from `Foo.prototype`. However it is currently not possible to have some functions inherit from a prototype other than `Function.prototype`, so there is no advantage to use `new Something` to create a function.

---

Since you are not using `prototype` in your example, it doesn't matter though. Simply return a function from `Fetch`:

```
var Fetch = function(host, username){
  function fetch(path) {
     console.log("Fetching " + fetch.username + '@' + fetch.host + path);
  }
  fetch.username = username;
  fetch.host = host;
  return fetch;
};
```

Now you can call `Fetch` with or without `new` <sup>**</sup>, it doesn't make a difference:

```
var a = Fetch(host, username);
// same as
var a = new Fetch(host, username);
```

Note that I changed `this.username` to `fetch.username` in the above example. Every function has its own `this` value which *does not* refer to the function instance itself by default, so `this.username` would not work.

This would allow changing the host or username after the creation via `a.username = 'something else';`, etc. If you don't want that, simply change `fetch.username` to `username`.

---

**: If the function *explicitly* returns an object, then `new` will return that value instead of the newly created object inheriting from `Fetch.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some kind of inheritance, you can ask your constructor to create and return a new function you'll prototype thanks to `setProtototypeOf`:

```js
const Fetch = function (host, user)
{
  var fetch // new instance of function, relay to model
  
  fetch = function(path) {
    // note we use the closure on instance 'fetch'
    return Fetch.model.apply(fetch, arguments)
  }
  
  // 'setPrototypeOf' is not as borderline as '__proto__',
  // but it has some caveats anyway. Check for example MDN
  // about this.
  Object.setPrototypeOf(fetch, Fetch.model)

  if (host) fetch.host     = host
  if (user) fetch.username = user
  
  return fetch
}

// we name 'model' here; it also works if we 
// say 'prototype' instead.
// It would have been both more meaningful and more confusing at the
// same time, as the prototype would not get used the standard way.
Fetch.model = function (path)
{
  console.log("Fetching " + this.username + '@' + this.host + path)
}
Fetch.model.host     = 'localhost'
Fetch.model.username = 'peter'


var fetch = new Fetch // 'new' is not needed: can say '= Fetch()'
fetch.host = 'paradise'

fetch('/register')
```

```html
See console output below
```