# How to create a function that can't be used as constructor

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function in javascript which can't be called as constructor like lets say if function is `function SomeFunction(){}`, on calling it like `new SomeFunction()` it should throw an exception but calling it without new should work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am curious to understand if there is a way to know inside a function if it's called with new or not.

Comment: please show the function

Comment: Yes, it's *possible* but it seems to be an XY problem. What is the real issue you want to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a function is called as constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use an es6 arrow `=>` function for this, as they are not allowed as constructor functions.

```js
let SomeFunction = ()=>{ console.log("called");}
SomeFunction();
//Error for arrow function
new SomeFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target). This is a special property, which is set when the function is called as constructor. See the following example.

```js
function test() {
  if (new.target) {
    throw new Error('Can not call as constructor');
  }
  
  return 'test';
}

console.log(test());
console.log(new test());
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor call creates an instance, so you can check if an instance is not created.

```js
function SomeFunction () {
 if(this instanceof SomeFunction)
  throw('constructor called');
 console.log('function called')
}

SomeFunction();

new SomeFunction()
```