# Create a class that is callable and with a callable constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Such as with the [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object.  How can a class be made to have a static method that can be called just by calling the class itself, but also have a normal callable constructor?

Comment: When a function is called as a constructor, the value of `this` is a new object that has the function as its constructor. If a function doesn't see that being the case, it can behave differently than it would if called as a constructor.

Comment: @Pointy That's not what I mean, they would be two separate methods

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're talking about. There's only one `Boolean` function. It can be used as a constructor or as a function. There are not two of them, just one.

Comment: @Pointy See my answer, essentially I was looking for the ability to write different behavior depending on if the reference was called a constructor or not, such as with `Boolean`

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but please note that what you ended up doing is pretty much exactly what I said in the original comment.

Comment: FWIW, functions in JavaScript can be *callable* or *constructable* or both. "Normal" function definitions create a functions that are both. Functions/constructors created via `class` are only constructable and arrow functions (and methods I believe (not sure)) are only callable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create this type of construct as a function, setting properties on instances using `this`:

```js
function MyBool(value) {
    this.value = !!value

    return !!value
}

console.log(MyBool(1))
console.log(new MyBool(1))
```

This is also the way classes were created in JS before the `class` keyword was included in the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just shortname to get you method in special place you can create scope and put method in variable.

Example:

```js
// GLOBAL SCOPE

{
// create local scope
// create variable
const methodByClass = myObject.getData;

// use it method
methodByClass();
}
```

Hope it helpful for you

Comment: No, this isn't what I meant.  Instead, I am wanting to have a single reference that is both callable, and has a constructor

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MyClass(x) {
  if (new.target) {
    this.x = x * 2
   } else {
    return x * 2;
   }
  }
  
console.log( MyClass(3) )
console.log( new MyClass(4) )
```

I found the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor/31060154#31060154)

Comment: Right, exactly, and there's only one function as I said originally in my comment.